# I have problem with textview text alignment

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I am displaying my OCR text in an text view but some lines in my text view are not reaching to the screen width.But some lines are reaching to the end.I have no idea how to do that please help me.

If you see my output in text view I still have a space to extend my line but it is displaying as a new line

my text view output

```
It is with great enthusiasm that I accept the Foreign 
Service Officer position with the
Department of State. 
I feel confident that I can make a significant contribution to the
agency.
```

> xml

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff006064">
    <Button
        android:text="Pick Image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MyButton" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="295.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No Text"
            android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" 
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

> .cs file

```
TextRecognizer txtRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(ApplicationContext).Build();
                if (!txtRecognizer.IsOperational)
                {
                    Log.Error("Error", "Detector dependencies are not yet available");
                }
                else
                {
                    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().SetBitmap(bitmap).Build();
                    SparseArray items = txtRecognizer.Detect(frame);
                    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); i++)
                    {
                        TextBlock item = (TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i);
                        strBuilder.Append(item.Value);
                        strBuilder.Append("/n");
                    }

                    int myLimit = 8;
                    string sentence = strBuilder.ToString();
                    string[] words = sentence.Split("/n",' ');

                    StringBuilder newSentence = new StringBuilder();

                    string line =".";
                    foreach (string word in words)
                    {
                        if ((line + word).Length > myLimit)
                        {
                            newSentence.AppendLine(line);
                            line = " ";
                        }

                        line += string.Format("{0} ", word);
                    }

                    if (line.Length > 0)
                        newSentence.AppendLine(line);

                    txtView.Text= newSentence.ToString();


                }

            }
```

Comment: could you provide the OCR text source ?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 android:layout_width="350dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

**Edit:**  Based on your comment, it looks the issue could be in the C# code where your original string from the OCR may contain "\r\n" or "\r" line breaks, and you're only looking for "\n" breaks.

So, I would change

```
string[] words = sentence.Split("/n", ' ');
```

to

```
string[] words = sentence.Split(new[] { " ", "\n", "\r\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

to see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work out for me